# Fetch information from an API before sending the request upstream

Tags: nginx

Is it possible to send a http subrequest in a location block and use the response in the proxy_pass directive?

**use case**

My upstream application needs some additional information from an API.
I've written a location block that proxies request with the proxy_pass directive.
Before nginx sends the request to my application. I'd like to send an HTTP request to my API and use several response headers
as request headers to my application.

This is the outline of what I want to achieve:

```
server {
  server_name ...;
  location {
    # perform subrequest to fetch additional information from an api

    proxy_pass myapplication;

    proxy_set_header X-Additional-Info "some information from the subrequest";
  }

}
```

The behaviour is similar to the [auth_request module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_auth_request_module.html). However, I can't find documentation of sending an additional blocking HTTP request before inside a location block using standard nginx configuration.

Comment: What information do you require from the subrequest?  Can you provide more context?  The question is very broad as-is, because getting random parts from the first request would be a huge exercise in itself. (Using a header from the first request in the second one would be more reasonable, for example.)

Comment: It would be fine if I could read the headers from the response of the subrequest towards the API. Let's assume the information is available in the `X-My-Value` header. How would I be able to send a subrequest, store the value and pass it to the proxy_pass directive?

Comment: Any feedback on the proposed answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do it using regular `nginx` directives but it's quite easy using [lua-nginx-module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module).

> This module embeds Lua, via the standard Lua 5.1 interpreter or LuaJIT
>   2.0/2.1, into Nginx and by leveraging Nginx's subrequests, allows the integration of the powerful Lua threads (Lua coroutines) into the
>   Nginx event model.

Here's how to accomplish what you need:

1. create a directory `conf.d/`
2. put 2 files `test.conf` and `header.lua` into it (see the contents below)
3. `docker run -p8080:8080 -v your_path/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d openresty/openresty:alpine`
4. curl http://localhost:8080/

#### test.conf

```
  server {
    listen 8080;

    location /fetch_api {
        # this is a service echoing your IP address   
        proxy_pass http://api.ipify.org/;
    }

    location / {
        set $api_result "";
        access_by_lua_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/header.lua;
        proxy_set_header X-Additional-Info $api_result;
        # this service just prints out your request headers
        proxy_pass http://scooterlabs.com/echo;
    }
}
```

#### header.lua

```
local res = ngx.location.capture('/fetch_api', { method = ngx.HTTP_GET, args = {} });

ngx.log(ngx.ERR, res.status);
if res.status == ngx.HTTP_OK then
  ngx.var.api_result = res.body;
else
  ngx.exit(403);
end
```

#### results

```
curl http://localhost:8080/
Simple webservice echo test: make a request to this endpoint to return the HTTP request parameters and headers. Results available in plain text, JSON, or XML formats. See http://www.cantoni.org/2012/01/08/simple-webservice-echo-test for more details, or https://github.com/bcantoni/echotest for source code.

Array
(
    [method] => GET
    [headers] => Array
        (
            [X-Additional-Info] => my-ip-address
            [Host] => scooterlabs.com
            [Connection] => close
            [User-Agent] => curl/7.43.0
            [Accept] => */*
        )

    [request] => Array
        (
        )

    [client_ip] => my-ip-address
    [time_utc] => 2018-01-23T19:25:56+0000
    [info] => Echo service from Scooterlabs (http://www.scooterlabs.com)
)
```

Notice the `X-Additional-Info` header populated with the data obtained in `/fetch_api` handler

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I was hoping it could be done within nginx itself without relying on lua. But I'm in a position where I can use lua for the project. Thank you very much!